# How to use effective caching in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, multithreading, caching

i try to use effective caching but i face to face a problem. For example; i have 5 user  they have used my app. user1,2,3,4 only fill grid by searcing(Caching is run!!!). on the other hand user5 adding new row. i want to refresh my cach data when adding new row. i read Multi threading to do that

```
code>using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;

namespace WebApp.Caching.Threading
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FillCache();

        }
        void FillCache()
        {
            using (var myCtx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                if (!(FlyAntCache.Exists("test")))
                {
                    List<Table_1> toolStoreList = myCtx.Table_1s.ToList();
                    FlyAntCache.Add(toolStoreList, "test");
                }
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                WaitCallback method1 = new WaitCallback(ControlAllChanging);
                bool isQueued = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(method1, new ManualResetEvent(false));

        }

        protected void ControlAllChanging(object state)
        {
            if (FlyAntCache.Exists("test"))
            {
                using (var myCtx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
                {
                    List<Table_1> list;
                    list = myCtx.Table_1s.ToList();
                    List<Table_1> listCache = FlyAntCache.Get<List<Table_1>>("test");
                    bool IsIntersect = list.Except(listCache).Count() > 0;

                    if (IsIntersect)
                    {
                        FlyAntCache.Clear("test");
                        FillCache();
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Search
            using (var  myCtx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var Qry = myCtx.Table_1s.
                                  FromCache<Table_1>("test").
                                  AsQueryable().Where(t => t.ad == TextBox1.Text.Trim());
                GridView1.DataSource = Qry;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

        }
     }
}
```

#### My Scenario:

LOOK please :http://i53.tinypic.com/20pdc41.png
[image]

i really control if another user change my data, i must refresh my cache. is there any sensitivity to CAPTURE any new changing update new row save. for example :
1) i must capture new update . this mechanizm  must run when changes occurs
2) i must capture new save. this mechanizm must run when new row adds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure what you're asking.  My best guess is it sounds like you're trying to let a cache know when its data is stale.

Most caching implementations have this built in. Basically, you can expire a cache item (usually be removing it from the cache) when it has been updated.

For example, if you're just using the plain old built in caching that comes with ASP.net:

```
private static Cache Cache;

public void AddItem(string data)
{
    //Do a database call to add the data

    //This will force clients to requery the source when GetItems is called again.
    Cache.Remove("test");  
}

public List<string> GetItems()
{
    //Attempt to get the data from cache
    List<string> data = Cache.Get("test") as string;

    //Check to see if we got it from cache
    if (data == null)
    {
        //We didn't get it from cache, so load it from 
        // wherever it comes from.
        data = "From database or something";

        //Put it in cache for the next user
        Cache["test"] = data;
    }

    return data;
}
```

**UPDATE**  I updated the code sample to return a list of strings instead of just a string.  This should make it more obvious what is happening.

To reiterate, the GetItems() call retrieves a list of strings.  If that list is in cache, the cached list is returned.  Otherwise, the list is retrieved and cached / returned.

The AddItem method explicitly removes the list from the cache, forcing the requery of the data source.

Comment: @programmerist - I updated my answer to make it more obvious what is happening.  This example clears the cached list whenever an item is added.  Is this doing what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but are you looking for events? You could set up events in your caching mechanism to fire when an update occurs.

[Here is a googled example](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html)

Comment: I added a link to delegates/events in the answer